# close a port from go code - not cmd to lsof

Tags: go

```
Env 
os: MacOS
go version: go1.14.3 darwin/amd64
```

I have a grpc server running and it does not always close the port (out of my control).

Do you know if it is possible to close a port from code?

It looks like you can do - but I need the pid?

```
err := syscall.Kill(<PID>, syscall.SYS_KILL)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("success")
}
```

I use to have this working in Powershell, but would like to move it to Go:

```
# lsof -ti tcp:$Port | xargs kill
Write-Host "Before: lsof -i :$Port"
lsof -i :$Port
$OutputVariable = (lsof -i :$Port | awk 'NR==2 { print $2 }') | Out-String
Write-Host "Process killed: $OutputVariable"
Stop-Process -Id $OutputVariable
Write-Host "After: lsof -i :$Port"
lsof -i :$Port
```

Comment: How is `net.Dial` supposed to help find the PID of the process that's listening?

Comment: Thanks, removed net.Dial

Comment: You'll need to do what `lsof` does: find the inode for that open socket using `/proc/net/tcp`, find the corresponding file descriptor in `/proc/[pid]/fd` to find the correct `pid`, then kill it. See details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996242/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-that-is-listening-on-a-certain-port-programmatic). It's probably easier to just execute `lsof` from within Go. Or even easier, use `fuser -k -n tcp <port>`.

Comment: You basically have three choices: 1) implement lsof/fuser yourself with all the bugs that entails 2) find a library that does it (ditto: bugs) or 3) exec a thoroughly well used utility like `lsof` or `fuser`. We can help with 1) and 3) if you try it and run into issues. You're on your own for 2). Anything you do will rely on either existing utilities or a well structured `procfs` which boils down to the same.

Comment: Thanks @Marc I will settle with using lsof - now I have it working in Powershell.

Comment: @Marc based on the use of PowerShell in the question this is most likely on Windows, which does not have `/proc`.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually on MacOs - I will update the question

Comment: The `lsof` part kind of gave away the unixy bit. I'd recommend `fuser` if available on Darwin, it's more focused than lsof and can do the killing for you.

Comment: fuser -k is not available on stock macOS. The only fuser flags are `fuser [-cfu]`.